# ACF Saving and updating fields in Ajax with custom front end form

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, ajaxform

Wondering if anyone knows any built-in function in ACF to **create or update any type of given field**.

I have a custom front-end form which fields follow this format:

```
<input type="text" name="acf-repeater_field_key-1-sub_repeater_field_key-2-subfield_key">
```

I have tried the code below in the back-end, after serializing the form data and sending it via Ajax

```
foreach ($serialized_values as $name => $value {
    $meta_key = str_replace('-','_', $name);
    update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $value);
}
```

This works fine for updating fields, but not for creating new ones. It seems that ACF is handling the database entries in a more complicated way.

Inspecting the ACF attributes they add to their own fields, I have seen the following:

```
name="acf[repeater_field_key][1][sub_repeater_field_key][2][subfield_key]"

id="acf-repeater_field_key-1-sub_repeater_field_key-2-subfield_key"
```

I guess that information may be enough for some function to save or create the field, but I cannot find what function is that.
I'm focusing on the nested repeaters because they seem to be the most complex type of field, but ideally, I would like this function to save or update any type of field.

Thank you

Comment: update_field does not seem to work with nested repeater fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736805/acf-update-field-into-nested-repeater-field

Comment: update_sub_field does not work for creating new rows